# RecyclerView expanding background

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, background

I have a RecyclerView in which I add items regularly. I want the background of the RecyclerView to expand while the list of items grows.

For example, if the list has two items and a new one is added, a new part of the background is discovered, and so on...

## What I expect

The complete RecyclerView is as in the image below. The user can only see a part of it, but discovers the rest when he/she scrolls up or down (which is why RecyclerView exists, I believe).

[image: background example]

Here we can see that the whole background is actually expanding beyond the screen's top and bottom border. So whenever the user scrolls the RecyclerView, the background moves with it (matching the movements of the list).

I'm completely lost with that, do you have any idea how to achieve such a behavior?

Comment: Did you try setting the height of the recycler view as wrap_content and giving it a background different from the background of the parent?

Comment: Yes actually, but if I do it that way the background stays fixed, and it doesn't follow the items when I scroll.

Comment: What do you mean by "follow the items when I scroll"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize I wasn't very clear in my explanation... I've edited my question to make it clearer.